# Windows 10 Full Drive Format Fails

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I recently bought two USB3 external hard drives that I want to do a full (not quick) format on using the Windows formatter. For whatever reason though, I keep getting an error for both drives stating that Windows could not complete the format. I have tried formatting these drives using different machines all running the latest version of Windows 10, but without luck. I am wondering now if this is an issue with Windows, as I was recently having problems with trying to do a quick format on the SD card I use for my Raspberry Pi. Is there something I can do to fix this or is this a known issue that I need to wait for Microsoft to hash out?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the hdd not Windows, have multiple 4TB external drives and I can do a full format on them

Comment: @Optionparty I don't want to use FAT32 on these drives. The FAT32 file system is too outdated.

Comment: @Ramhound Okay, point taken. But what is the chance that two HDDs would fail at the same time? I am trying the format again through a USB2 port. So far, I have not received any errors.

Comment: You don't indicate the error nor provide the model number

Comment: @Ramhound The error message was "Windows was unable to complete the format." It would pop up a few minutes into the formatting process. Here is a link to the page I purchased the HDDs from: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1236407-REG/fantom_gf3b4000u_4tb_g_force3_usb_3_0.html

Comment: Ugh Fantom Drives (I have nothing but problems with that brand).  This drive come with an external power suppply?  What else is connected to your USB 3 Hub?

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm, that's interesting. I have plenty of them and have never had issues like this prior to now. Yes, it comes with an external power supply. There was nothing else connected to the USB 3 Hub. I disconnected everything except the mouse and keyboard which are not even on USB 3 ports.

Comment: Have you tried formatting from Windows Shell or Linux.